# How can I merge the bands for each ID to create two multi-band TIFFs in R?

Tags: raster, r, export, function, rasterstack

I have 16 separate raster files, named by ID and band, for 8 bands and 2 IDs. How can I merge the bands for each ID to create two multi-band TIFFs?
Here are my data:

```
    dput(rastlist)
    c("7398_b10_new.tif", "7398_b2_clip.tif", "7398_b3_clip.tif", 
"7398_b4_clip.tif", "7398_b5_clip.tif", "7398_b6_clip.tif", "7398_b7_clip.tif", 
"7398_pan_new.tif", "9609_b10_new.tif", "9609_b2_clip.tif", "9609_b3_clip.tif", 
"9609_b4_clip.tif", "9609_b5_clip.tif", "9609_b6_clip.tif", "9609_b7_clip.tif", 
"9609_pan_new.tif")
```

I managed to do it this for the first 8 elements of my list. Here's how:

```
setwd("mydir")

#first import all files in a single folder as a list 
rlist <- list.files(path = "mydir", pattern='.tif$', all.files=T, full.names=F)

#substract the  first 8 raster of the list
n = tail(rlist,8)

#stack layers
rstack = stack(n)

#substract the first element of the list
one = tail(n, 1)

#get the first 4 letters of the first element of a list (to be used as raster name of the raster stack)
rexport = substr(one, 1, 4)

writeRaster(rstack, filename = rexport, options = "INTERLEAVE=BAND", overwrite = T, format = "GTiff")
```

How can I generalize this?

Comment: Is this a better way of posing the question: "I have 16 separate raster files, named by ID and band, for 8 bands and 2 IDs. How can I merge the bands for each ID to create two multi-band TIFFs?" because as its written its a bit unclear to me. Might be worth editing for clarity.

Comment: What do you want to generalise it to? Any number of sets of N raster files with names in some pattern?

Comment: I want to create a function that takes a list of N raster (multiple of 8, e.g. 16, 24, 32 etc), performs the above code to the first 8 raster of the list, then then next 8 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
  rlist <- list.files(path = "mydir", pattern=paste0(ras, ".*.tif$"), all.files=T, full.names=F)
  rstack = stack(rlist)
  writeRaster(rstack, filename = rexport, options = "INTERLEAVE=BAND", overwrite = T, format = "GTiff")
}

rass <- unique(substring(rastlist, 1, 4))

lapply(rass, stacker)
```